# summation of series (binomial theorem)

Tags: combinatorics, summation, negative-binomial

I need help in solving this question.
If $n \in N$,$n\ge 3$ 
then the value of $(1)n-\frac{(n-1)}{1!}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)^2}{2!}-\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)^2}{3!}+.....$ upto n terms

any help hint will do.

My attempt:
$S=\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r) {(n-1)\choose r}$. after this i am not able to do it.

Comment: I do not understand the question, can you also provide some examples and the things you have tried to prove it ?

Comment: Is the denominator of the fourth terms $1!$ or $3!$ ?

Comment: Also, is the exponent of $n-3$ in the fourth term $3,$ or indeed $2$?

Comment: Did you forget an $(-1)^r$ factor in the summand?

Answer (score 1):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} : $

Denoting $ S_{n} $ your summation, $ R_{n}=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}{\left(n-1-r\right)\binom{n-1}{r}} $, we have :

$$ S_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}{\left(n-r\right)\binom{n-1}{r}}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n-1}{r}}+\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}{\left(n-1-r\right)\binom{n-1}{r}}=2^{n-1}+R_{n} $$

Now making a change of index by symmetry in $ R_{n} $, we get that : $$ R_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}{\left(n-1-r\right)\binom{n-1}{r}}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}{r\binom{n-1}{r}} $$

Thus, $$ 2R_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}{\left(n-1\right)\binom{n-1}{r}}=\left(n-1\right)2^{n-1} $$

Hence $$ S_{n}=2^{n-1}+\left(n-1\right)2^{n-2}=\left(n+1\right)2^{n-2} $$